Braid form of general link embedded in a genus $g$ surface?
It is known that a general braid word for a $T(m, n)$ torus link is $(\sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots\sigma_{n−1})^m$; for example, see here. Does anyone know if there is a braid form for a general link embedded in a genus $g$ surface?

Any knot can be embedded on a genus $g$ surface for some $g$.  And there is not a general braid word for every knot.  There is too much freedom on where and how the strands can go on $g>1$.  But there are some "nice" knots on higher genus surfaces that you can play this game with, for instance twisted torus knots.
